# Image Picker - Ionic Native Component

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to use [this](https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker) image picker source to select multiple images(25+) from the devices camera roll but am receiving errors when I try to access the gallery. So, I essentially just have a button which starts this function below and I receive errors immediately.

**Here is the image picker code**:

```
 private openGallery (): void {
    let options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      quality: 75
    }

    this.imagePicker.requestReadPermission().then(res=> {
      console.log("res" + res);
      this.imagePicker.getPictures(options).then(
        file_uris => console.log(file_uris),
        err => console.log('CHEESE', err)
      );
    });
  }
```

**Here are the console logged errors:**

1. Method: `'sudo ionic cordova run browser'`

   **Error:**

> cordova.js:1003 Error: exec proxy not found for :: ImagePicker ::
>   getPictures home.ts:81 CHEESE Missing Command Error

2. Method: '`ionic serve`'

   - Returns an error and doesn't enter gallery

**Trouble Shooting**
- Delete and reinstall node modules
- Delete and reinstall image picker
- Ensure latest version of plugin
- Verified plugin in package.json
- Tested on iOS and Android
- Tried changing the code, requesting permissions etc.

No luck. More advanced debugging on checking plugin properly installed and configured up next.

> Error: plugin_not_installed

For version reference here is the package.json

```
{   "name": "IonicAngularFire",   "version": "0.0.1",   "author": "Ionic Framework",   "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",   "private": true,   "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"   },   "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/image-picker": "^4.9.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.8.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.11",
    "cordova-browser": "5.0.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.4",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-image-picker": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^1.1.19",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "firebase": "^5.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.26"   },   "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.10",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"   },   "description": "An Ionic project",   "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-telerik-imagepicker": {
        "PHOTO_LIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": "your usage message"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-image-picker": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser",
      "ios"
    ]   } }
```

I have searched for alternatives or solutions to my issue but have found mostly outdated conclusions. Any advice is appreciated. I'm currently using the ionic native camera plugin to get images, however my purpose for the app requires 25+ images to be uploaded so single image selection is not ideal.

Again, here is the ionic native component I am using and the github source -

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/

https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

**UPDATE:**

3. Xcode Simulator (Success!!!!)
   I went ahead and built my app for iOS and ran it on the Xcode simulator and wow! It works!

I'm not sure this is ideal but at least I now know it is working properly. I'll continue debugging to see if it will serve my purpose and post updates.

**FINAL UPDATE:**
   It is apparent that the ionic native image picker does not work on the ionic dev app for iOS or Android, however it does work in production on the Xcode simulator ( not tested for android simulator but similar result I'm sure ). I'll be working on other things since debugging through Xcode is tedious.

07/13/18 using ionic 3 angular 5

Comment: First of all, Image Picker plugin (https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/image-picker/) supports only on iOS and Android (not in the browser). So, you should test it on iOS or Android. For Android platform, you can run the application with the command `ionic cordova run android`.

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko Thanks for the advice, I'll continue testing on mobile platforms exclusively.

Answer (score -1):

```
 let options = {
      width: 500,
      height: 500,
      quality: 75,
      maximumImagesCount: 10
    }

add -    maximumImagesCount: 10
```

Comment: Add explanations.